# Any ip address that doesn't resolve to a domain can be considered to be not someone's home connection ip?

Tags: networking, ip

Is it save to state that an IP address, that is hitting my web server, that does NOT resolve to a Hostname can never be someones home connection but a proxy/Vpn?

Comment: No, not at all. There are many, many IP addresses which do not have DNS associated with them. Businesses often have blocks of public IP addresses, and most of those will not have a DNS entry associated with them.

Comment: @Ron Maupin  uhhhhh.... "Businesses often have blocks of public IP addresses"...... that doesn't read as home connections. And i know that when i acquire ip addresses from my hosting provider that those do NOT resolve to a hostname unless i create dns records.

Comment: Right, but what I am saying is that you cannot assume that because an IP address can't resolve to a host name (reverse DNS) that it is, or is not, a home network address or proxy/VPN.

Comment: @Ron Maupin When i nslookup my home ip i get static.kpn.net. When i nslookup some other ip i get an answer like "axx-xxx-xxx-xxx.adsl.xs4all.nl". The answers are not empty so to say. When i do a nslookup with an ip that i acquired the answer will be empty. Isn't it typical for VPN providers to NOT register their blocks by dns so they can't be identified as belonging to ie HMA (Hide my ass).

Comment: But you simply cannot guarantee that any ip address without a reverse lookup is something like that. The company that I work for, a very large business, has many thousands of public IP addresses, and the vast majority of them will not have a reverse lookup, nor are they proxy/VPN addresses.

Comment: Yes, but they are most definitely not addresses handed out by regular isp's to home connections? Isn't that a safe assumption to make?

Comment: No. Not all ISPs will set up reverse DNS for their addresses. Most do, but you cannot guarantee that. Nor can you guarantee that some company (ISP or otherwise) has not set up misleading reverse DNS records.

Comment: Ok. Most of them do thus. So if i detect some suspicious activity on my webserver at a specific point in the code -i placed some code to send me an email if that happens - and the ip address involved can NOT be resolved .....? Does that make it most likely to be an address used for hiding ones self?

Comment: Not necessarily. You seem to be under the impression that this is something that is policed in some way. Anyone with a public IP address, and there are individuals who have public IP addresses, can simply not register a reverse DNS, even if they have a forward DNS, or they can register a different reverse DNS from the forward DNS. There is no accountability.

Comment: I'm logged in from my work WiFi without using proxy or VPN and my ip doesn't resolve to a domain.

Comment: Is your goal to detect whether the person is hiding himself using VPN or proxy? If that's it, then you can do port scanning on known proxy ports to verify if it is a proxy.